# Mockito JUnit test for simple api call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, sonarqube, mockito

I consider myself a novice at unit-testing, completely new to Mockito and junit. I have to write unit-tests for some simple api-calls. But my test seems somewhat pointless to me, I can't tell where I am going wrong. I have added a method to an existing web-service, ManagerWS.java , See Below.

**ManagerWS.java Method:**

```
public String healthCheck(String userId) { 
    String healthCheckUrlEndpoint  = this.baseUrl()+"/health";
    logger.debug("Calling health check: {}", healthCheckUrlEndpoint);
    HttpHeaders healthCheckHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    healthCheckHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    healthCheckHeaders.add(USER_KEY, userId);
    healthCheckHeaders.add(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_VALUE);
    healthCheckHeaders.add(Constants.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_HEADER, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().toString());
    healthCheckHeaders.add(CORRELATION_HEADER, myService.get(AppLoggingMDCService.LOG_KEY_REQUEST_ID));
    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(healthCheckHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> response;        
    try {
        response = makeRequest(HttpMethod.GET, healthCheckUrlEndpoint, request, String.class); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception encountered during health check", e);
        throw e;
    }       
    logger.debug("RESPONSE : http status: {} - body: {}", response.getStatusCode(), response.getBody());
    return response.getStatusCode().toString();
}
```

The logic is simple. Construct the url, create headers and add headers to the request. make the request and extract the status-code from the response. Here is my test. NOTE: the class is using **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)** and I am using **@Mock for dependencies** and **@InjectMocks for the local instance ManagerWS**. ManagerWS.java is the service calss being tested.

**TEST-CLASS TEST-Method:**

```
    @Test
    public void testHealthCheck() throws Exception {
    //Given
    managerWS = new ManagerWS(templateFactory, configParamService, mdcService, env);    
    String url = "http://baseurl/health";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();    
    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);   
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    //when
    when(managerWS.makeRequest(HttpMethod.GET, url, request, String.class)).thenReturn(response);
    String actualStatus = response.getStatusCode().toString();  
    //then
    Assert.assertEquals("200",actualStatus);
}
```

To me this test seems stupid (*for want of a batter word*). I basicall set the status to give a "200" and assert that what i set is "200". That is not really making much sense.To me it literally does nothing. I tried using spy(ManagerWS.class). But I am literally grasping at straws without the full understanding.

SonarQube still complains with "Not covered by unit tests". I cam completely stumped as to how else to write this test. I also have to do similar tests for three other calls.

I am a total novice to testing and I cannot see my mistake. Please advise.

Comment: Assuming you use Spring `RestTemplate` to make the requests, why not verify that the outgoing request has the required parameters? Something like described at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template?

Answer (score 1):

> SonarQube still complains with "Not covered by unit tests".

Your unit test doesn't test from the entry point of the method to test : `healthCheck(String)`, so it is not covered by unit tests. 
Besides, you also mock the part of the method that you want to test :

```
when(managerWS.makeRequest(HttpMethod.GET, url, request, String.class)).thenReturn(response);
```

So indeed your approach looks wrong.
In fact, writing an unit test for this code looks wrong too or at least looks like  a white box test with few value.
Why ? 
Your logic depends on :

```
response = makeRequest(HttpMethod.GET, healthCheckUrlEndpoint, request, String.class);
```

But you can know if it works only at runtime, with a running HTTP Server. 
So the single thing that you can do is mocking everything, spying the object under test and verifying that each statement in the implementation is performed : no readable test, no robust and few/no value.

Your method that relies essentially on side effect would make more sense to be tested with as an integration test :

```
  ManagerWS managerWS; // real ManagerWS implementation without mock

  @Test
  public void healthCheck() throws Exception {
    //Given
    String url = "http://baseurl/health";
    // When
    String actual managerWS.healthCheck(url);
    // Then
    String expected = "...";
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
```

As a side note, if you used Spring, I would advise you to look at test slicing `@WebMvcTest` that focuses on the web part of the component under test. It allows mainly to test the HTTP part/logic (headers, request, response).